# How do I add an email verification function in wordpress blog comment

Tags: php, wordpress

Email verification on a wordpress blog. Before commenting on a blog, the user has to sign up for email verification process.

Answer (score 1):

You could find a plugin which forces the user to confirm the email account when they sign up. Maybe [WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-email-verification/) or for more customasation maybe try [Pie Register](http://wordpress.org/plugins/pie-register/)

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear tho...

Things that we'll need to know is if you have access to the files containing the necessary code that will post the comment on a certain topic.

If so, you could use PHP's built in function:

`filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

This function is PHP 5.2+

Here is a [link to filter_var() on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

Here you can find all the documentation you need to validate e-mail address.

**NOTE**

It is not possible to check if ANY e-mail is actually a real address, unless you send a validation e-mail to check if it's not some fakemail like 10minutemail or something.

If you don't have access to the PHP file, an alternate solution would be to validate through JavaScript, this can be disabled however and the regex needed is not 100% accurate and usually very chunky.

Your best bet is to change this in PHP to atleast check if a valid e-mail address is filled in.

e.g. example@example.com as a valid e-mail.

Hope this helps.